# Uploading And Reading CSV-Parse File

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to read a csv file with multiple same colums using `Node CSV-Parser`

```
 'from' ' 'to' 'from' ' 'to' 'from' ' 'to'
 'Germ' ' 'NL' 'Turk' ' 'US' 'Nile' ' 'BR'
 'Germ' ' 'NL' 'Turk' ' 'US' 'Nile' ' 'BR'
 'Germ' ' 'NL' 'Turk' ' 'US' 'Nile' ' 'BR'
 'Germ' ' 'NL' 'Turk' ' 'US' 'Nile' ' 'BR'
```

And below is my code:

```
req.file('ratefile').upload(function (err, uploadedFile) {
        if (err) return ResponseService.json(500, err, 'Uploaded Failed');

        console.log(uploadedFile.length) //

        if (uploadedFile.length) {
            rs = fs.createReadStream(uploadedFile[0].fd);
            parser = parse({columns: true, trim: true}, function (err, data){
                var record = {};
                console.log(data);
                _.forEach(data, function(datum, index){
                    var routeName = datum['from'] +"-"+ datum['to'];
                    console.log(routeName);
                    record.name = datum['from'] +"-"+ datum['to'];
                    record.to = datum['to'];
                    record.from = datum['from'];
                });

                return ResponseService.json(200, res, 'file successfully uploaded');
            });
            rs.pipe(parser);
        } else {
            return ResponseService.json(500, res, 'Please upload a file')
        }
    });
```

And when I run that, it only the last column on the csv file.

```
  'from' ' 'to'
  'Nile' ' 'BR'
  'Nile' ' 'BR'
  'Nile' ' 'BR'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I bet it is because your columns have duplicate names...The data you gave does not really look like a CSV... What is the column separator ?

Comment: It isn't and I use a comma separated CSV and yes, it's because the columns are duplicated. What if I want to access it like that? Can't I? The data I'm reading are very large and I can't start editing

Comment: No you can't. Each column must have a unique name

Comment: Why don't you parse it by yourself? Create writable stream and separate the line by the comma, that way you'll get an array which you can access.

Comment: I know with the [`fast-csv`](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) module you can disable object creation (`headers: false`) and have it output arrays instead. However you'll have to ignore the first row since it will think it is a normal data row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will parse into something like

```
{
  "from": "Germ",
  "to"  : "NL",
  "from": "Turk",
  "to"  : "US",
  ...
}
```

And of course it's not valid JSON, look at the duplicate keys. So last key value pair will actually overriding previous pair.

In your line

```
parser = parse({columns: true, trim: true}, function (err, data){
```

Use function, or `null` as `columns` value, like

```
parse({columns: null, trim: true}
```

And print out your parsed result, and then modify by your own needs. It can also use `function`, but I don't pretty sure `function` can solve your problems, since it will still parsing your single csv line into single `object`.

Comment: Yeah. I tested that too and I saw the response in the form of an array with objects and I was avoiding not using columns:true....but had to use this method too. Thanks anyway

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko is your problem already solved or not? Mark this topic as solved by pick an answer to avoid misleading unsolved topic :)